# Show up modal in navbar

Tags: javascript, development, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a navbar where I want to show a modal if I click into one item's Title.

So now I show my navbar in JS menupopulator like this:

```
 function completeMenu(data, target) {
var prefix = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
var sufix = "</ul>";
var items = data.d.results;
var menu = "";
for (var item in items) {
    if(items[item].Funcion != null && items[item].Funcion != ""){
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + " id='"+items[item].Funcion+"'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
    }
    else
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
```

So that I want is where `items[item].Title` is == `SignIn` show modal instead open another link... can I do that?

I have tried something like this:

```
for (var item in items) {
    if(items[item].Funcion != null && items[item].Funcion != ""){
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + " id='"+items[item].Funcion+"'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
    }
    else
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";

    if(items[item].Title == "SignIn"){
     "<button type= button class=btn btn-default data-toggle= modal  data-target=#mymodal">"</button>"
    }
   }

    }
```

And then in view:

```
<div id="mymodal" class="fade modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeader"></asp:Label></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Test modal</p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

----------------------------Update-----------------------------

There is my change but when I change it, I get only a label saying "true"

```
 function completeMenu(data, target) {
var prefix = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
var sufix = "</ul>";
var items = data.d.results;
var menu = "";
for (item in items) {
    menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
    if(items[item].Title == "SignUp"){
menu += "<button type= button class=btn btn-link data-toggle= modal  data-target=#mymodal">""
}
}

$(target).html(prefix + menu + sufix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript method: `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showmodalDialog(options)`

Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx) for syntax and example.

Comment: I try other way, can you look up my edit please?

Comment: It looks like you're using bootstrap? I can't help you with that. But it does look like you have a lot of erroneous spaces, and too many quotes and in the wrong place at the end... `"<button type='button' class='btn btn-link' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'>"`